# Can I use Coldfusions cffile action="upload" with an image destination url?

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, verification, cffile

I need to loop over a list of pathnames and image names and verify that the file exists and is a jpg/png, before changing it's size and storing it to the server.

I want to use this:

```
   <cffile result="upload" action="upload" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" destination="#tempDirectory#" nameconflict="overwrite" />
    <cfset testFilePath = tempDirectory & upload.serverFile>
    <cfimage name="tempFile" action="read" source="#testFilePath#" />
    <cfif NOT isImageFile( testFilePath ) >
        <cfset fileDelete( testFilePath ) />
        <cfthrow type="FileNotFound" message="#tx_settings_icons_error_img#" />
    <cfelseif NOT listfindnocase(allow, upload.serverfileext) >
        <cfset fileDelete( testFilePath ) />
        <cfthrow type="FileNotFound" message="#tx_settings_icons_error_file#" />
    </cfif>
```

But my problem is, I don't know how to upload a file from a path like

```
 http://www.some.com/folder/image.jpg
```

**Question**:
Can I just `read` the image, perform my validation and then store to disk or do I need to upload the image first. I will have to loop through a list of 500 images and am reading `cffile action="read"` shouldn't be used with large files. What would be an alternative to check image files for correct type, `isImage`and file extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally use `cfhttp` to read the image and verify that I have it, then convert to a valid `cfimage` object and do my manipulations then. You can see my process in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536815/convert-an-image-from-cfhttp-filecontent-to-binary-data-with-coldfusion/1537433#1537433).

Answer (score 2):

Use cfimage to read the file from a URL. Set the source to be that URL. Then, you can write that to disk locally.

Code example:

```
<cfset imageData = ImageRead("http://tutorial28.learncf.com/img/bgHead.png") />
<cfimage action="write" source="#imageData#" destination="#expandPath('test.png')#" />
```