# How to validate and delete an image in Coldfusion uploaded by cfhttp?

Tags: validation, coldfusion, cfhttp

I'm running `Coldfusion8` and need to pick up and store images from a remote location and am trying to validate whether whats being picked is actually an image.

I usually do validation like this:

```
<cffile result="upload" action="upload" accept="image/png" filefield="Dateiname5" destination="#tempDirectory#" nameconflict="overwrite" />
    <cfset testFilePath = tempDirectory & upload.serverFile>
    <cfimage name="tempFile" action="read" source="#testFilePath#" />
    <cfif NOT isImageFile( testFilePath ) >
        <cfset fileDelete( testFilePath ) />
        <cfthrow type="FileNotFound" message="#tx_settings_icons_error_img#" />
    <cfelseif ImageGetHeight( tempFile ) NEQ 512 or ImageGetWidth( tempFile ) NEQ 512>
        <cfset fileDelete( testFilePath ) />
        <cfthrow type="FileNotFound" message="#tx_settings_icons_error_size#" />
    <cfelseif NOT listfindnocase(allow, upload.serverfileext) >
        <cfset fileDelete( testFilePath ) />
        <cfthrow type="FileNotFound" message="#tx_settings_icons_error_file#" />
    </cfif>
    <cfset fileDelete( testFilePath ) />
```

So I'm uploading to a secure folder, perform validation for type, dimensions and file extension and discard from my secure folder if any of the validations fail.

I now need to validate extension and type using `cfttp` and am not getting it to work.

Right now I have this:

```
<cfhttp timeout="45" throwonerror="false" url="#variables.testFilePath#" method="get" getasbinary="yes" result="variables.objGet">
<cfset varaibles.allow = "png,jpg,jpeg">
<cfset variables.objImage = ImageNew(variables.objGet.FileContent)>
<cfif NOT isImageFile( variables.objImage ) >
    <cfset variables.failedLoads = variables.failedLoads & img_paths.bilddateiname & "(" & tx_gen_filetype & "), ">
    <!--- <cffile action="delete" file="#variables.objImage#"> --->
<cfelseif listFindNoCase( variables.allow, variables.fileExt) EQ 0>
    <cfset variables.failedLoads = variables.failedLoads & img_paths.bilddateiname & "(" & tx_gen_fileformat & "), ">
    <!---  <cffile action="delete" file="#variables.objImage#"> --->
<cfelse>
    <cfdump output="e:\website\stokkers\test2012\dump.txt" label="catch" var="it's an image allright">
</cfif>
```

**Questions:**
Can I use `isImageFile` here at all or is the image I create not an image... I can check for? Also, if any of the validations fail, how to I delete the create image again (from memory I assume)? `cffile action="delete"` doesn't seem to work?

**EDIT:**
This is what I'm checking right now:

```
<cfhttp timeout="45" 
    throwonerror="false" 
    url="#variables.testFilePath#" 
    method="get" 
    useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201 Firefox/2.0.0.12" 
    getasbinary="yes" 
    result="variables.objGet"
    >
<cfset variables.objImage = ImageNew(variables.objGet.FileContent)>
<!--- returns NO --->   
<cfdump output="e:\website\stokkers\test2012\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#IsBinary(variables.objImage)#">

<cfif NOT isImageFile( variables.objImage ) >
    <cfdump output="e:\website\stokkers\test2012\dump.txt" label="catch" var="not an image">    
    <!--- <cffile action="delete" file="#variables.objImage#"> --->
</cfif>
```

The file is a `jpg`, still I'm always failing `isImageFile`

Comment: Check my previous answer. You need to convert the `fileContent` from the `cfhttp` request into a binary object first.

Comment: hm. your previous answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536815/convert-an-image-from-cfhttp-filecontent-to-binary-data-with-coldfusion/1537433#1537433). So should I use: binaryEncode/binaryDecode as per [CF8 docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_a-b_31.html)?

Comment: d'oh, I was thinking of a different answer to a different question. So let's back up... What error are you receiving? Which line in your code isn't working? If you try to create an image from a response that isn't an image, then you should get an error, which you can `try/catch` to show the proper error.

Comment: see my edit above. I can't test with `isImageFile`

Comment: Right, you can't check with isImageFile, because that requires a path on disk. But When you call `ImageNew`, if the `fileContent` is not a valid image, it should throw an exception, which you can `catch` and then behave accordingly. If it does not throw an exception, then it is a valid image.

Comment: ok. Learned something. If you want to make this an answer, I will check. THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `isImageFile` expects a path based on the ColdFusion livedocs. What you want to do is call `ImageNew`, and if the `fileContent` is not a valid image, it will throw an exception. You can then `cfcatch` that exception and then behave accordingly. If it does not throw an exception, then it is a valid image.

Comment: ok. I think I have it. Last question: how do I discard my `variables.objGet` if the validation fails. Do I just set it to =""?

Comment: Or you can do `StructDelete(Variables, "objGet")`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution comes from a combination of Brian's and Dan's answers:

```
<cfparam name="form.fileUpload" default="">
<cfif len(trim(form.fileUpload))>
   <cftry>
      <cffile action="readBinary" 
            file="#form.fileUpload#" variable="aBinaryObj">
      <cfset myImage = ImageNew(aBinaryObj)>
      <cfset imgOkay = "Yes">

      <cfcatch type="any">
         <cfset imgOkay = "No">
      </cfcatch>
   </cftry>    

   <cfif imgOkay eq "Yes">
       <cffile action="upload" 
           fileField="fileUpload" destination="C:\docs">
       <p>Thank you, your file has been uploaded.</p>

   <cfelse>
      <p>We're sorry. The file chosen is not an image file,
         or it is corrupt, so it cannot be uploaded.</p>
   </cfif>
</cfif>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" /><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't know ColdFusion enough to judge this but this SO markup seems a bit fishy to me. Could you edit it to use proper markup?